# Escaping a string with quotes in bash alias file

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to put the following command in my `~/.bash_aliases` file:

```
grep screen /var/log/auth.log|grep "$(date|awk '{print $2" "$3}')"
```

I've tried putting the following in the alias file:

```
alias unlocks=grep screen /var/log/auth.log|grep "$(date|awk '{print $2" "$3}')"
```

but I get the following:

> bash: alias: screen: not found
>
> bash: alias: /var/log/auth.log: not found

Presumably, this is because of the spaces in the command string, which would normally be solved by quoting the entire string, but I'm already using two types of quotes and I can't work out how to escape them correctly.

Please can someone help?

Comment: `date|awk '{print $2" "$3}'` seems a bit weird. What if you use the `date` parameters to build the desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alias foo="my command with\"quotes\""` should work most of the time

EDIT: As `bash` will evaluate the string, you also need to escape other special characters like `$`

In your case: `alias unlock="grep screen /var/log/auth.log|grep \"\$(date|awk '{print \$2\" \"\$3}')\""` should do the trick.

Comment: That's worked - cheers. Could have sworn I'd tried that already haha.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because it expands `date` at the time when the alias is defined. OP probably wants "when I run the command" instead. So you need to protect/escape the `$()` as well.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Of course, special characters like `$` need to be escaped as well. I edited my answer

Comment: As bash will evaluate the string, you also need to escape other special characters like $

Comment: ``alias git-authors="git shortlog -sne | awk '{\$1=\"\"; sub(\" \", \"\"); print}'"``

Answer (score 6):

Don't try to make something this complex an alias. Define a function in `.bashrc` instead.

```
unlocks () {
    grep screen /var/log/auth.log | grep "$(date +"%b %d")"
}
```

Also, don't use `awk` when you can just adjust the output of `date` directly. However, you *can* use `awk` to replace both instances of `grep`:

```
unlocks () {
     awk -v date=$(date +"%b %d") '/screen/ && $0 ~ date' /var/log/auth.log
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way and a hard way.

The simple way: Put the code into a script file called `unlocks` inside the folder `$HOME/bin`. In most systems, that folder gets added to the path. Use `chmod +x $HOME/bin/unlocks` to make the script executable.

The hard way: You can use nested quotes but it's ugly, brittle and ... I don't recommend it. But if you must, it would look like this:

```
alias unlocks='grep screen /var/log/auth.log|grep "$(date|awk '"'"'{print $2" "$3}'"'"')"'
```

To get a single nested single quote in a single quoted string, you need `'"'"'` The first tick ends the current string. The `"'"` gives you a single quote which the shell will append the current string. The last tick then continues the string.

```
alias unlocks="..."
```

won't work in this case because it will immediately run `date|awk '{print $2" "$3}'` and put the result into the alias.